# Error running Jest and pdfjs-dist v4, not handling .mjs files

Tags: jestjs, ts-jest, babel-jest

I am using the npm package `pdfjs-dist@4.0.269`.

When I run my code by `ts-node src/pdf-reader.ts`, everything works fine.
But, when I try to test it using Jest, I am receiving the error

```
...w, __webpack_exports__updateTextLayer as updateTextLayer, __webpack_exports__version as version };
             ^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'

       5 |   TextItem,
       6 | } from 'pdfjs-dist/types/src/display/api.js';
    >  7 | import { getDocument } from 'pdfjs-dist';
```

My current configs are:

```js
// babel.config.cjs
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    ['@babel/preset-env', { targets: { node: 'current' } }],
    '@babel/preset-typescript',
  ],
};
```

```js
// jest.config.cjs
/** @type {import('jest').Config} */
module.exports = {
  testEnvironment: 'node',
  moduleNameMapper: { '^(\\.|\\.\\.)\\/(.+)\\.js': '$1/$2' },

  verbose: true,
  globalSetup: './test/setup/jest.setup.ts',
  globalTeardown: './test/setup/jest.teardown.ts',
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['./test/setup/jest.setup-after-env.ts'],
  testTimeout: 15000,
};
```

How can I fix this error between .mjs files and Jest?